# Unknown class in Interface Builder file

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, class-reference

I created a fairly simple iPhone app.  Then figured I'd create an iPad version (Universal) of the app.  Tried using the 'upgrade' option and that didn't work-out.  So I created a separate universal app and copied the xib files into my project.  That didn't work out either, so I deleted the xib files (and their associated .m & .h files.

Now, when I run the iPhone version it gives me the Unknown class iPadSample1AppDelegate in Interface Builder file. error and UISplitViewController is only supported when running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad and then it exits.  So, I restored to the snap-shot I took before embarking on the iPad adventure... I get the same error.  I've tried the XCode search and Spotlight search.  There is no reference to that class or the UISplitViewController anywhere in my project, but for some reason XCode thinks that there is.

Is there some way to remove a reference that doesn't exist? LOL

Update:

It may have something to do with my XCode environment being jacked.  After finding a few other posts on here, I tried a Clean All / Build / Touch and when I did the touch, I got the following error in XCode:

> **Uncaught Exception:**
>
> -[XCBuildLogWarningMessage setFileLocations:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2014dd0a0

Anyway to reinstall XCode without messing up everything else?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It turns out the bits on the iPhone simulator were out of sync with XCode.  I did a 'Reset Content and Settings' and everything works :)  Who knew?

Comment: Thanks! You've just saved me time trying to debug this further. It makes sense now that the debug information we see is announced from the iOS Simulator. But what wasn't obvious was that the app wasn't getting freshly deployed each time. It's all very well clearing out the Derived Data in XCode 4's Organizer view, but if the IB files on the iOS Simulator are still old then it's no wonder it's throwing out odd error. Thanks for the discovery

Comment: I also had this problem, but this solution didn't work for me. My problem was related to the class not being included at Copy Bundle Resources. Cheers,

Comment: My symptom: Refactor->Rename, crash on launch with "Unknown class: TheOneYouDeletedDerp".  Sounds like there are similar issues with other valid solutions, but mine was fixed with this Reset solution if anybody has done the same thing.

Comment: I just deleted the app from the simulator and that worked.

Comment: Saved me after 2 hours debugging! used an ipod and uninstall the app was solve it, thx!

Answer (score 13):

If you go to Build Phases within your targets you will see Compile Sources. Make sure each of the m files you need are listed. If not, just add it here and the warning should go away.

Comment: Fixed it for me. Xcode has problems with adding/moving files.

Comment: Adding the files to Compile Sources did the trick for me, @Thromordyn might be right that Xcode isn't adding files properly.

Comment: This worked for me. I had rearranged the source files around into a real folder hierarchy so I don't have a long list of files in one folder (why isn't this is the default xcode behaviour?). Afterwards most of my source files simply weren't being compiled even though they are in the xcode solution!

Answer (score 7):

**I did some research** and found out that

`for my case`

**I just need to right click to complaining file in the Project Navigator.**

Choose `View/Utilities/Show File Inspector.` And for some reason the `Target Membership` was not selected.

That's why the linker says that it doesn't know the existence of the class.

I just ticked to choose it and everything works like a charm.

Comment: tyvm - u just saved me 2 hrs of debugging - IDEs are great when you know all the issues, but often a PITA when you're just learning...

Answer (score 7):

Right click on Storyboard --> Open As --> Source Code

Find your unknown class name in the storyboard source file.  It may be because you have accidentally assigned a custom class name for one of your UIView subclass'.

Comment: Exactly my case. And good to know a new way to open xib file

Comment: this should be right answer . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem but it was not solved by the solution above. I ended up getting it working by removing the "Main storyboard file base name (iPad)" entry from my info.plist file.

Answer (score 1):

what fixed it for me was t smply "delete" the ap in the simulator, and rebuild again.

Probably this class was still rerenced in local settings in the iphone simulator.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error appeared after refactoring class name. Somehow the classname not changed in the .xib file. I opened this xib-file in Textedit and replace all OldClassVC to NewClassVC. Then I saved xib-file and Cleaned project before new build. Project runs well.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Cocoa pods, drag the .framework/.a files to your projects' "link binary with libraries" section.