# Xcode 6 Bug: Unknown class in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I upgraded to Xcode 6 beta 4 and now my App continuously crashes with the message

> Unknown class X in Interface Builder file.

It crashes because supposedly Xcode can't find my custom classes that I have linked in my Storyboard but it shows that they are linked correctly in the Xcode interface.

I'm positive everything is linked correctly. My only other option may be to delete the entire storyboard file and start from scratch because it might be corrupted somehow.

Edit: I would also like to add that I tried cleaning, reseting simulator, messing with build phases etc. None of that works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416269/unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file

Comment: @ImreKelényi You are right. This happened to me again recently after doing what you just described.

Comment: This worked for me, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725881/unknown-class-myclass-in-interface-builder-file-error-at-runtime

Comment: It was typo for me, debug it to the Control element, till when it comes, select; View Controller > identity inspector > Custom Class > Class. delete that if that class is not defined.

Comment: PLEASE NOTE! This "error" can stem from different origins. If the accepted answer does not work for you then move down and try the next answer. The correct answer for my situation was the 5th answer.

Comment: If you're here because of the TextFieldEffects library (https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects/tree/1.1.1) like me, note that this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1511, accepted):

I resolved this issue as I was typing the question. I figured I'd answer my question and leave it here for anyone else who may face this issue when using Xcode 6 beta 4.

To resolve this issue, you need to select each of your custom class objects in Storyboard (this includes any custom views, even the custom view controllers themselves).

Then with those objects selected, open the identity inspector and under "Custom Class" you should see the Module option. Finally:

- Click inside the Module text box, and press enter.
- **Or** <sup>(update 2022)</sup>, check the "Inherit Module From Target" option.

That's it! The current module for all of my custom objects must have been internally incorrectly set somehow in Xcode 6 beta 4. But there was no visual indication of this in the inspector.

Note that if pressing enter inside the Module text box doesn't work, try selecting the arrow to the right and manually select your current module, then clear the text box and press enter. You can also try pressing enter inside the class text box (although this usually is to resolve a different issue).

Here is an image to make things more clear:
[image]

Comment: For me, clicking inside "Module" and pressing enter did not work consistently, but selecting the "Class" field (and pressing enter) always did the job.

Comment: I was getting this error and it happened to be because I changed my app name so all the modules were wrong.

Comment: @itedi good point, when I get a chance I think I'll add a "Causes" section and list everything that users report  caused the issue so we can get a list of what's leading to the issue.

Comment: gfrs: This is not working for me... Have you tried with Xocde 6 beta 6?

Comment: Doesn't work in the GM. What works is typing your module name manually.

Comment: What about nibs that are shared between two different build targets, in which case there are two different Swift modules? Is the only solution to port the shared code and resources over to their own module (thereby limiting to iOS 8)...

Comment: For me, the target was set correctly, but the class still didn't show up in IB. I noticed, though, that the "Location" of the file showed a path "Relative to Project" instead of "Relative to Group". Removing the file reference AND the group and re-adding it in the project root worked for me.

Comment: I have yet to find a solution. This might be the most frustrating bug I've ever encountered.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this, I don't think I would have got there otherwise. This fixed an issue that started happening after I added `@objc(...)` to one of my Swift classes.

Comment: The solution was different for me. You need to add the .m of the class to the build phase compiled sources of the target.

Comment: This error was caused for me by creating a new class and subclassing it from an already existing class I created. Not sure why that would cause that though.

Comment: I got the same issue but I only get the error message in console log without the app crash. And I've tried your solution, but my module name is empty so I've no choice but to leave it. Strange

Comment: My "Module" field wasn't causing problems. I only had issues with "Class" field, as my class was not selected properly due to copy-paste. After selecting the correct class for "Class" field had no more problems.

Comment: In my case, I had not added the `.m` file of the custom class to the **Compile Sources** list of my target.

Comment: for me, I had to manually drag and drop the implementation .m file in the "Compile Sources" section of Build Phases.

Comment: I was four hours into the rabbit hole when I finally found this post.  Thank you so much.  I almost gave up.

Comment: @EpicByte I am using 6.3. And an xib I created somehow decided it was too cool to have the module set for it. Don't know what i would've done without your answer!

Comment: Xcode sometimes puts source files in Base.lproj (when creating, or when copy to project if needed is checked when drag and dropping) and this prevents the file from being added to compiled sources, once clean that up, and add it to compiled sources, you must click the class name and hit enter as noted in other comments

Comment: Works for XCode 7.1.1 too

Comment: This issue is still present in XCode 7.2. This solution worked.

Comment: In my case in xCode7.2 this wasn't a conversion issue but popped up when I created a custom UIViewController class and named it incorrectly initially. Not sure it's related, but the solution worked.

Comment: In my case I had the custom class in a local framework, and clicking enter in the module field didn't work. I had to manually select the framework in the module field for it to work.

Comment: I had to clear out and reenter the name of my custom class, then it found the module correctly.  WThis is with XCode 7.2 as well.

Comment: do you guys know what exactly has to be written in the Module field ? Selecting/Deselecting/Reselecting the Class field doesnt change the module field at all. And btw, any of my other VCs have the module set, they all have "None" causing no problem. Why should this one have it ?

Comment: Just ran into this on Xcode 7.3 solution worked beautifully.

Comment: does not work for xcode 7.3.1, with swift component in objective-c project

Comment: I just got bit by this AGAIN. I had forgotten about it and spent another couple hours thinking I had hooked a nib up incorrectly or something. Still happens in Xcode 7.3.1!!

Comment: this worked for me to get rid of the warning/error although i noticed that at least the background color specified in my storyboard did show up in the running app despite this console log

Comment: Thank you thank you. For posterity, this occurred in my project when I renamed the app. The module name is not updated to the new app name so its trying to reference the class in the old project. It manifested as an unwind segue not firing.

Comment: You saved my life. Until xcode 8.2.1 have this problem.
I found that it add some parameters into xib file. (Marked with highlight)

<collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" reuseIdentifier="MyViewCell" id="XdY-Ke-DXa" customClass="MyViewCell" `customModule="MyProject" customModuleProvider="target"`>

Comment: Thank you!  My app has multiple targets so I needed to press "enter" in the Module field in order to set it to "Current - (target name)"

Comment: This is still an issue in Xcode 8.2.1.  Thanks for the helpful answer!

Comment: This is still an issue in Xcode 8.3.1... such a shame

Comment: Xcode 8.3.3 user here, thanks, it solved my problem.

Comment: Xcode Version 9.0 beta 6 and the issue isn’t fixed 

Comment: Note that if you're using Carthage, the dropdown for Module may not show anything but you can just manually type in the name of the module and it'll work

Comment: You saved my life. The actual problem was we have to Tick `Inherit Module From Target` option in the storyboard file.

Comment: XCode 10.0 user here

Comment: When I hit the 'return key' on the custom class it clears out the module to be empty (just on this one scene in the storyboard). and then the module drop down is empty (although I have 2 targets that work with all my other view controllers). Maybe it has something to do with using this storyboard and the class that is not recognized is an objective-c class, whereas the rest of the project is in swift.

Comment: Enabling `Inherit Module From Target` took the correct target module

Comment: Xcode normally checks the box for you if you change then class - sadly if you use a find and replace it doesn't - Thanks for your post

Comment: Oh my... I don't know how I would have figured this out without this post! THANK YOU! This worked for me just now after I converted a custom TableViewCell from Objective C to Swift in Xcode 11.

Comment: It's 2020, I'm on Xcode 11, and this is still happening. Thank you for this solution though!

Answer (score 102):

Sometimes Xcode missed **`customModule="AppName" customModuleProvider="target"`**

To fix it, open storyboard as source code and replace this line:

```
<viewController storyboardIdentifier="StoryboardId" id="SomeID" customClass="CustomClass"
sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

to this:

```
<viewController storyboardIdentifier="StoryboardId" id="SomeID" customClass="CustomClass"
 customModule="AppName" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

Comment: Actually in my case i had to remove `customModuleProvider`, then the error went away.

Comment: Guillermo, still happening in Xcode as of end of March!

Comment: @MaciejSwic Removing the `customModuleProvider` did it for me as well, thank you!

Comment: what about for xib files?

Comment: Still happening... it's things like this that make me want to cry :(

Comment: That was life saver. This bug still happens in Nov, 2015 with xcode 7.1.

Comment: Thanks for this. This fixed everything on Xcode 7.2!!

Comment: This worked for me, after the issue was introduced by migrating to Swift 3 in the Xcode 8 beta.

Comment: this glitch happened to me after I renamed a collection view cell xib file. But manually selecting module as shown got it working again

Comment: xcode 8 beta 6 - similar problem, and now resolved. thanks.

Comment: thanks for this.  My problem was that there was two storyboardIdentifiers="StoryboardId". I tried refactoring a storyboard that was created with Xcode 7 I believe.  it was 3 years old. REBUILD the storyboard from scratch.

Comment: Happened with Xcode 12.5.1 and working with this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 73):

I had this problem after renaming a swift class. Solved it by using the @objc directive:

```
@objc(ForumTopicListViewController) class ForumTopicListViewController
```

Comment: This fixed it for me, I had `@objc class X` and changing to `@objc(X) class X` worked.

Comment: You can also try to delete your derived data see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039932/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode6

Comment: Had this problem after renaming the default ViewController class from the Single View project template. I wonder what magic was used so that the `@objc()` directive was not needed for the 'original' ViewController class...

Comment: I goes the opposite side. I had specified the module name in Storyboard file but also added @objc directive.

Comment: This worked for me. ObjC/Swift hybrid project. New VC + Xib in Swift. Xib was not working. VC was blank. Added this, works.

Comment: This works, despite having way less upvotes than some other answers. Thank you my saviour!

Comment: Worked for my first Swift class in a hybrid project in Xcode 8. I already had @objc but had to make it @objc(ClassName) class ClassName as described.

Comment: Did NOT work for me. :( Neither is the solution of Module name working.

Comment: Same problem here. If you have @objc(ForumTopicListViewController) it won't find it in Interface Builder you need @objc FormumTopicListViewController class UIViewController

Answer (score 70):

**Project with Multiple Targets**

In my case I am  working on Project with multiple Targets and the issue was "inherit from Target" was unchecked. Selecting "inherit from target" solved my problem

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Solved the issue I was seeing very quickly.

Comment: I had a similar situation. (XCode 9.4.1) I created an iOS app called FilesTestA, with a custom UIView called MxFileView (which consisted of MxFileView.swift and MxFileView.xib). Then I added another target: a Today widget ("FilesTestAWidget"). Solution for using MxFileView in the widget: (1) class = "MxFileView"; (2) check "Inherit Module from Target" (or uncheck it and manually enter "FilesTestAWidget"); (3) in the app target, make sure that both MxFileView.swift and MxFileView.xib include FilesTestAWidget in their Target Membership.

Comment: This happened to me on a new project from the default template in Xcode 10.1 (a single iOS app target, and 2 test targets). The checkbox was unchecked for all of my custom view controllers (and so the placeholder text was "None"). After going through and checking the checkbox for every custom view controller in my storyboard, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 59):

This worked for me..

Check your compiled source, whether that file(e.g; ViewController.m) is added or not, in my case ViewController file was not added so it was giving me the error..

[image]

Comment: @CarmenA You only ever add '.m' files to `Compile Sources`. This really is the correct (& only) solution for some.

Comment: I tried several of the other solutions with no luck. This did the trick. For some odd reason one target was missing the one source file that was giving me fits.

Comment: for me too.. Happened because of some get conflict resolution

Answer (score 48):

This can happen in any Xcode above 6.0. It happened to me after renaming some ViewController classes in Swift project (but I guess it will happen with Obj-C too). You just have to open the interface builder, go to Identity Inspector of ViewController that had its class renamed, select class and press Enter. That will reassign renamed class to selected ViewController and also reset Module Value which gets lost after renaming the class.

Update for Xcode 8.1 (probably 8.0 too):

Xcode 8.1 just crashes. Simply and annoyingly just crashes and doesn't print anything. I was chasing that phantom crash for an hour just to find out that it was this very same thing - unassigned class in IB. If you're getting some phantom crashes, double check IB for unassigned classes first.

Comment: thanks for this. it appears that following your suggestion causes Xcode to update the module (under the class in IB) from None to Current. i'm thinking the issue is that simply entering the name w/out hitting enter fails to trigger a module update by Xcode.

Comment: This worked for me.  I inadvertently renamed a controller class, so it obviously no longer existed when the view controller was loaded.

Answer (score 47):

Enabling `Inherit Module From Target` took the correct target module. That solved the issue.

[image]

Comment: Confirm. This helped me solving the issue.

Comment: I usually have this issue when I convert a view controller from Objective-C to Swift. I retype the last letter and press Enter. Should do the trick as well.

Answer (score 33):

Sometimes the controller you are providing loses its target membership from the current application. In that case, pressing enter on the "Module" field will do nothing. Go to the controller and make sure that it has target membership set to the current app.

Comment: This was the problem for me as well - multiple targets lead to the class file accidentally not being included in the target I was building.

Comment: I merged files and misses this in one of my targets, great answer

Comment: Good one, merge pbx broke the target membership values.

Answer (score 33):

My answer: set custom Module equal to the custom Pod name (in my example - custom class name) like on the screenshot attached

This solution is for a **specific case**: for custom **views** classes from **Pod** (or **Carthage**) framework.

Infrastructure: XCode8, Swift3

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Selecting the proper `Module` for my `Custom Class` I solved this problem .

Here it is :

[image]

Answer (score 18):

I fixed it by doing exactly the opposite of what ChikabuZ suggested (thanks for pointing it out, though). In the storyboard file, find this:

```
<viewController storyboardIdentifier="StoryboardId" id="SomeID" customClass="CustomClass" customModule="AppName" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

and replace it with this:

```
<viewController storyboardIdentifier="StoryboardId" id="SomeID" customClass="CustomClass" sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

I can't believe how many hours I'm losing getting around bugs in the Swift compiler and Xcode 6

Answer (score 13):

I faced this problem in **Xcode 8**, to resolve it I had to modify storyboard in the text editor.

In general, look up for your control and remove `customModule` and `customModuleProvider` from control entity.

Did a trick for me.

Comment: Hah! Nice hack :)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem.

In my case, Xcode wasn't adding my custom class to: Target > Build Phase > Compile Sources.

So I recommend you to verify if your CustomClass.m is there.

[image]

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This is what happened to me, and fortunately found my way out! I was coming here to answer but you were first. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 11):

You need to check the box "Inherit Module From Target" Checkbox

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I faced this issue in Xcode 6.1 when I removed `Main.storyboard` , the `LaunchScreen.xib` file and the default `ViewController` classes from my project.

I fixed it by deleting the `Launch Screen File` and `Main Interface` entries from `Info.plist`

Answer (score 9):

Check if your class has right **Target Membership**.

Answer (score 8):

I googled everywhere for this. None of the answers work for me until i met 1 dude who asked me to move my project folder to desktop. It just worked automatically. Apparently if you have you project folder to deep in many folders, XCODE actually breaks.

Comment: I got this problem in Xcode 7 beta 5 again since I got it in Xcode 6 before. This time, this method works for me.

Comment: In visual studio there is a similar problem. But over there, we get a clear warning message saying the path is too long and things cannot be added or edited. Not sure if its the same thing with XCODE, but after that episode i keep all my projects either in documents or desktop and never had this problem again. I even gave this advice to someone using Xamarin Studio and it also worked for them...

Answer (score 7):

These steps work for me.

1) Clear Derived Data.
2) Remove .h and .m files 
3) Create .h and .m files Again

Comment: This worked for me as well. I even made it work without clearing derived data.

Comment: This was worked for me, thanks a lot Arwin, But still I am not getting that why it's raising such error because I did not modify anything in the class or in IB before

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by opening my storyboard file as source code and using command-F to search for my unknown class and delete the custom class associated with it.

Answer (score 6):

What @gfrs said is correct, you need to set the Module. However I once ran into an issue that my class wasn't listed in the `Class` dropdown. Eventually I removed the swift file, re-started Xcode and re-created the file. Finally the class was listed and could be used in Storyboard.

Also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10157567/58107), which looks like to solve the 'real' problem I encountered.

Comment: Removing and re-adding class file worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by typing in the Module name (unfortunately the drop list will show nothing...) in the Custom Class of the identity inspector for all the View controller and views.

You may also need to indicate the target provider. To achieve this objective you can open the storyboard in sourcecode mode and add the "customModuleProvider" attribute in both ViewController and View angle brackets.

Answer (score 6):

My solution (Xcode 8.1 Swift 3.0):

Unknown class ***xxx*** in Interface Builder file.

Open StoryBoard as Source Code and search for ***xxx***. Remove attribute which contains value ***xxx***. Build and Run.

Comment: WTF? This was absolutely necessary for me, thank you. I had to delete the `customModule="" customModuleProvider=""`

Comment: If we try to publish an application to the app store that contains an error like this, the application is refused without thought.

Comment: I disagree. I just submitted a build that I had to modify this way to TestFlight and it's ready for Beta Testing... we shall see what happens on the actual app store, but it's an IB bug IMO. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I added a flag `-ObjC` to `Other Linker Flags` in project settings to make it work. Also I tried with `-all_load` flag and it worked well too.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the **class** referenced in the Storyboard / xib did not have **Target Membership** set.

To fix, give that class's `.h` and `.m` files the same Target Membership as your other classes.

[image: No target membership set.]

Comment: This was my problem, but while trying various solutions I caused the problem that Epic Byte's answer fixes. You must have your source code in the target you are building, but also in IB you need to set the view controller to be part of the current target.

Comment: Target membership was my problem also, looked everywhere, but thanks to this answer I could solve it.

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to remove @objc from Custom class definition.

Comment: Some example with explanation would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d). I think the problem appears if you renamed your App / Xcode Project.

My solution was to add the module name in the interface builder manually.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the problem when I ported the storyboard from Swift project to Objective-c project, noticing [vvkuznetsov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27763697/2361752), it turned out the two project using same identifier. I "Product -> Clean" and tap Enter key on the Module and Class text field. the issue went away.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this along the lines of what Laura suggested but I didn't need to recreate the files.

Using XCode 4, in the Project Navigator, select the .m file that contains the class that it is complaining about

Go to View->Utilities->Show File Inspector
(this will show the File Inspector to the right, with that .m-file info)

Open the Target Membership section and make sure that your target is selected for this .m-file

When I added my .m file to my project, it didn't add it to my default target for some reason and that caused me to get the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was user error.  I had a generic UIView in my storyboard and in the Custom Class section of the Identity Inspector I had accidentally changed the name from UIView to gibberish.

All it took to fix was to change it back to UIView.

Comment: I did the same thing, but I had accidentally added the Custom View Controllers name to the ViewControllers root view's custom class section. 

So I was looking to see why View Controller wasn't able to be found when it was the root view the whole time.

Answer (score 1):

What only worked for me is actually adding the module name to the xib file...

Sooo, the xib files look like this:

```
mymodule.MyViewController.xib (Module being the name of the proyect, usually)
```

HORRIBLE solution in my opinion, but that is supposedly how Apple wants us to do it now.

[This question shows 3 possible work arounds back in beta 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538995/cant-load-uiviewcontroller-xib-file-in-storyboard-in-swift/25539016#25539016) ... apparently Apple has not been very helpful in this situation according to some because they call it "Working as intended."

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after I added a new target, then created a new class using the 'New File' dialog but accidentally failed to check the new target as well as the original target in the creation dialog, so the object was only added to my original target. The solution was to delete the source files (remove reference only) then add them back using 'Add Files', this time checking both targets.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was different for me. You need to add the .m of the class to the build phase compiled sources of the target.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Select your unknown class file, open file inspector tab, check your target name in `Target Membership`. There you go.

Answer (score 1):

On me it happend because my project was called with "ä,ü,ö"

Answer (score 0):

I faced such a problem on Xcode 6 when I deleted the already included ViewController.h & ViewController.m files from my new view based project, and deleted the scene that was related to this class from storyboard, Xcode cashes these files in derived data folder, so if you try to go to Window -> Projects -> your_project and delete the derived data everything will go fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use spaces in the project name, otherwise the Custom Class will not find your own classes.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a problem when I created a project with the same name that already existed in my projects directory (though it was deleted some time ago). I wrote my solution there https://stackoverflow.com/a/27763697/1654692

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me because my class was marked with `@objc` and in sotryboard it couldn't find the module. Removing `@objc` fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but not the same fix.

The project folder was kinda corrupted so i had to copy my project folder to another folder, for example your desktop and after that open the project.

When it opened go to your interface builder project and you will see he recognise your script, Then you click indeed on the name of your script and press enter, u will see the module input will fill it self.

And it will work like a charm! :D

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when *nothing* else did. From the project directory in terminal:

```
[~/Developer/MyProject] grep -rn ViewController * | grep -i xib
```

Open the matched files as source code in Xcode and change any instances of ViewController to what you actually need. In my case the file I needed to open as source was Main.storyboard and I changed instances of ViewController to DetailViewController.

I deleted two files from Xcode and main.storyboard which is what I believe caused this issue for me to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

In mij case the ViewController.h/m where in a lib. The projects still builds but since Xcode 6.3 the above error was shown at run-time. Moving both files back into the project solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with Spring class. And this error happend to me because i used folder as reference when moving whole folder class to project instead of creating groups. So this was my solution, dont use folder as reference but create groups.

Answer (score 0):

in my case , i setup app as universal app, so xcode creates two storyboards.but i was only using(designed) only iPhone storyboard. and trying to run app in iPad.for resolve problem just need to make app as only for iPhone and works great.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Xcode 6.3 when  I add files to "myapp".
That's because I choose "create folder reference" instead of "create groups".I delete these files and add them again with the "create groups" option.And the problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I'm using Xcode7 + Swift2

Solved this problem by checking my code, I have this line in my viewController:

```
 self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Then I realized that I haven't get navigationController connected to the detail page. So if you're pushing a new ViewController with customized ID, better to check that.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related to a podfile framework (specifically the 'BWWalkthrough'). None of the above solutions worked for me, and no matter how I tried I couldnt get the module to point to my app.

What ended up working for me was removing the library as a podfile and add it directly to my project as a static library. Everything was hunky-dory for me after that. Not entirely sure what was 'broken' with the pod implementation of the class.

Comment: I had the same issue with custom pod - setting Module to the podname helped me, You can find here my answer with illustrating screenshot if needed.

Comment: Setting module as `BWWalkthrough` made the messages go for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was due to having our main storyboard set as the Launch Screen, and I'd get a console error (no crash) at app start for every custom view controller referenced in the storyboard.

We'd covered from XIBs and launch images to storyboards and I hadn't yet gotten around to getting the launch screen working again. When I finally got around to creating a bare bones launch storyboard with no custom view controllers (which aren't allowed) these console errors stopped appearing.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I was referencing a custom class in the storyboard (which matched to a .h file) but I didn't have an @implementation command in the .m file.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3** solution.

All these did NOT work.

1. Clicking on `Module` on right pane did NOT work.
2. Adding @obj did NOT work.
3. Restarting did NOT work.
4. Moving to desktop as xcode breaks for longer path is NOT working.
   ...

This worked finally.

Just **create new directory and create a new project** inside that. Add the files except Main.sotryboard.

Now copy the view controllers from previous project and paste it into new Main.storyboard.

Voila ! This works.

Comment: Can you check git and see what changed inside the storyboard? It would be good to be able to fix this manually if it's simple…

Comment: I haven't used git for this project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a `PyObjC` user and I had my `NSView` subclass in its own file. What solved this problem for me was to move the `NSView` subclass from its own file into my `AppController.py` file. This is the file that has the application controller in it.

Answer (score 0):

This really wierd when `XCode 10` stopped to "refine debugs".
In my case, i setted UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource with Storyboard and forget to implemente those required methods.
I just wanted to test the view first, before implement those methods, then crash! `XCode 9`, will warning about those methods, but `XCode 10`, really maked my code slow, not on this one, others i been thru this "error doubt".
Hope this help someone.
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me i've tried all the solutions in this question didn't work , i finally made it by .

copy the pod .h .m files into my project and imported the .h into my project c header.

then i went back to storyboard the class was `UICountingLabel` i removed it and hit enter
( empty no class ) , then i added it again and hit enter, worked successfully .