# Xcode 6 Beta 3/4/5/6, cannot connect IBOutlet or IBAction using Obj-C. Also, cannot select "Module"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I've got an issue with an app I'm writing where all of the `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` connections in Interface Builder have the "warning" icon, and no `IBOutlet` or `IBAction` connections show up as available from any of my custom classes.

When I try to select the "Module" for the custom class, there's nothing to pick. I read  [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file) that instructed me to simply click in the Module text field and press , but that did nothing for me. The other instruction (to click the right arrow) simply takes me to the class's source code.

Additionally, when I click the drop-down to select the class for the object, none of my custom classes are listed. This is true for `UIViewController` subclasses, `UITableViewCell` subclasses, `UIView` subclasses, etc.

When I run the app, the connections I had previously set are still intact and the app runs fine. If I re-open the app in Xcode 5, the connections are available and the classes show up in the Custom Class drop-down.

I can't run the app using Xcode 5 because I've added code that won't compile, so it gets really irritating to open the project in Xcode 5 just to make connections, then re-open the project in Xcode 6 to run it.

I am declaring all of my `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` connections in a private interface in my implementation file, but that's never been a problem before.

I'm using Objective-C, not Swift.

Surely I can't be the only one to have encountered this issue, right?

Comment: Have you tried a `Product -> Clean`. Or hold down option key then click `Product` then `Clean Build Folder...`.

Comment: @Fred Yes, I've tried all of those tricks, including manually deleting DerivedData, Clean, "Really" Clean, etc... Doesn't seem to help on mine. For now, I've got a workaround where I have both Xcode 5 and 6 open simultaneously and do my IB work in Xcode 5. Sucks, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

**You can also see that the link between the parent view and the custom class is broken (not visible anymore) which is a huge problem.**

I had the exact same issue with the app i'm working on actually, updating XCode from 5.xxx to 6.1. The workaround that worked for me was to remove the reference of every view controller and re-add them to the project...

**To everyone facing that issue, here's the (annoying) trick :**

- **Step 1** : select both .h and .m view controller files
- **Step 2** : remove the reference of those files
- **Step 3** : re-add the files to your project tree
- **Step 4** : open the storyboard, eventually re-build the project and smile

I can understand those things could be reaaally annoying, but it worked for me... Hope it will help someone else !

Comment: FWIW, the latest Xcode is working just fine for me (except it sometimes chokes on bigger Storyboards, especially iPad ones).