# Not able to assign custom viewcontroller in storyboard

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am absolutely clueless what happened to Xcode. I'm not even able to assign a custom ViewController to a storyboard ViewController. I get the error:

"Unknown class vcTest in Interface Builder file...........
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label"

vcTest is my custom ViewController. I saw several solutions to this in other posts but my problem seems to be a lot different.

In this test app, I have 1 ViewController:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class vcTest: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


}
```

The only ViewController in the storyboard is assigned to this ViewController, having 1 label outlet. vcTest does show up under: Build Phases -> Compile Sources. I must be totally missing something here or Xcode is absolutely broken. I even tried to uninstall and reinstall Xcode which did not help.... I have an other ungoing project were I discovered this issue and now it even comes up in this simple test app. What is going on here?

Note: this happened after upgranding from Yosmite 10.10 to 10.10.1.

edit:
so this is what i found out til now:
i somehow created one project where this does not happen, on all other projects it does. it did not specify anything special in the working project. what i noticed between the working and "codewise similar" non working is the module listed in storyboard. the working one shows : Current - projectname and the none working one shows None. i attached a screenshot. 
how can i change the model to current model?
(can not post images here is a link):
http://s14.directupload.net/images/141119/xn8jb7cw.jpg

Comment: Have you tried this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file

Comment: yes i have tried all those solutions

Comment: ok so after 8 hours i finally was able to fix this problem, i have no idea what happened there but i think xcode messed something up. as i mentioned the method in your link did not work for me. the module field still showed None for me. I had to manually enter the name of the module (wich was the name of the project for me). after that the custom viewcontroller was recognized again. hope i can help someone with that...