# Unknown class in Interface Builder file Xcode error

Tags: xcode

In the storyboard I'm getting a message Unknown class in Interface Builder file Xcode error. Then crashing with an unorganised sector for an nsarray that I have for the class.

This question couldn't get me an answer. [Xcode 6 Strange Bug: Unknown class in Interface Builder file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file).

Answer (score 1):

All i needed to do was go to the file inspector, target membership and tick the box.