# XCode 6: The custom class and the several project targets

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I would like to have both DEV & PROD versions of my app working on my iPhone at the same time.

So I created a new target AppNameDev with a different bundle identifier.
When I launch the app on my iPhone, I get the error :

```
Unknown class _TtC4Wesh10InviteCell in Interface Builder file.
```

My custom class `InviteCell` is not found by the new target's interface builder. How to tell it where to find the class ?

Answer (score 1):

When you click the InviteCell source file check from the File Inspector on right that both targets are checked. Or that the file exists in Build Phases - Compile Sources for both targets.

Comment: Actually that was done. According to the error description, the issue comes from the interface builder file.

Comment: The error may be misleading... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file

Answer (score 1):

You need to click "InviteCell" class file from left side on Project Navigator and then go to "File Inspector" and click both targets (DEV & PROD) from Target Membership on the right side. I hope that helps you. For example:

[image]

Pro Tip: If you are planning to create a new file, make sure to select both DEV & PROD version targets before you click to "create" button. It will save you a lot of time because you don't have to go back and forth.

Comment: Actually that was done. According to the error description, the issue comes from the interface builder file.