# Data cannot be presented on tableview(iOS Dev), what's wrong?

Tags: ios

I'm an iOS developer from scratch. Currently, I'm learning something about a tableview and getting stuck here. Granted, it's a quite rudimentary issue. But I cannot work it out!

The ideal situation should be a table with the first line of a label and a checkmark. I swear I have followed the tutorial with every step but the table in the simulator was somehow blank. There must be some subtle mistakes. I'm really confused. Now, my operation is fully captured and is enabled in the link. If someone could analyze my operation and point out my mistake I would be gratitude.

[hit this link to see my operation from YouTube](https://youtu.be/xWMFgtcSc6U)

[hit this link to see my operation from my Google Photos](https://goo.gl/photos/fw9yAmhCrBs5fixaA)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your video you named your custom class as `ChecklistViewController`, but the **Module** is none. I don't know why it becomes `none` because in my project it is `Current - Checklists` aka your current target. Would you try to click the blue arrow on the left and then, choose the right module. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file) may be also helpful.

[image]

Comment: i got it. Actually, the problem is that I enabled Source Control but I forgot to commit it.

Comment: @YiqunLiu  How did source control matter?

Comment: If a customized class was not committed to git, there will be a '?' at the end of the name of the file in file viewer so that the file cannot be recognized