# Objective-C project use Swift encounters a incompatible

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a custom `UIView` in xib and  fill out a custom class inherits `UIView`

[image]

the `FastThreeMenuView` use swift langue
then I get instance with this sentence:

```
FastThreeMenuView *menuView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FastThreeMenu" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
```

I check variable `menuView` the class type is `UIView`,but I use Objective-C to implement the custom `UIView`,I get the instance type is `FastThreeMenuView`, how to fix the Issue?

Comment: Is `FastThreeMenuView` a UIView subclass?

Comment: yes , it is a UIView subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Swift classes have namespacing.

You should set the `Module` in xib like so:

[image]

[Xcode 6 Strange Bug: Unknown class in Interface Builder file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file)