# Xcode 7.1 Swift 2 Unknown class in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa

I've created new Cocoa Touch File. Named it SwipingViewController.
[image]

Then try to add Custom Class to ViewController.

And when I run the app I receive an error

> **2015-10-09 10:53:25.054 ParseStarterProject[5369:389307] Unknown class SwipingViewController in Interface Builder file.**

[image: Unknown class SwipingViewController in Interface Builder file]

Related:
[Xcode 6 Strange Bug: Unknown class in Interface Builder file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file)

Here is my [projects files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8d2o2vugrfh5no6/Tinder%202.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

In storyboard below the Custom Class field the module is set to None. Change that to your app module or just remove and enter class again, it should set to default like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks. That solves the problem. For some reasons I have not this - Current - Parse Project. I reload my Mac and maybe that also helps.

Comment: Thanks, it helped when getting back to legacy project.

Comment: Still happening when setting up a new project in XCode 8.3.2 (module was set to None). But your suggestion works.

Answer (score 16):

For me the problem was that the class was not part of the `Target Membership`.
Just add the class to the target, and you should see it back on the interface builder.

[image: Target Membership]

Comment: I faced same issue in XCode 9.3 and i did exactly the same way it works , even by changing module inside xml file din't work , so this answer should work in latest xcode and old one too. Nice catch.

Answer (score 10):

Still seeing this problem with **XCode 8.2.1**, but I am able to fix the problem by modify these in the storyboard xml file:

1. Delete `customModuleProvider="target"` in the **viewController** tag:

   ```
   - <viewController ... customModule="Flights" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
   + <viewController ... customModule="Flights" sceneMemberID="viewController">
   ```
2. Delete `customModule="Flights" customModuleProvider="target"` in the widget tag (in my case, a **label** tag):

   ```
   - <label ... translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="PzF-6K-Hpi" customClass="YZLabel" customModule="Flights" customModuleProvider="target">
   + <label ... translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="PzF-6K-Hpi" customClass="YZLabel">
   ```

I find that step 1 is very important too to resolve the crash/warning and cannot be skipped.

Comment: thank you you save my day
I only need to add :                                                  customModule="ObjProject" customModuleProvider="target"

Answer (score 3):

I resolved a similar issue by adding '-ObjC' to 'Other linker flags' in the 'Build Settings' of my project.

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar issue as well. I had a ViewController with a TableView in it, and the tableView's custom class was called 'ViewController'.  I just deleted the custom class for the tableView and the error went away.

Comment: Thanks.  I solved it using your method.  I accidentally added "MyCustomViewController" to the custom class for both ViewController and TableView inside.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by applying view controller initialise. View-controller basic declaration of view did load method and class implementation in *.swift class shows in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by manually writing the module name in the storyboard, under the class name. In my case it was the same name as the class, but it may differ.

Answer (score 0):

For me: for table view cell in 'Indentity Inspector' unchecked 'Inherit Module From Target' and cleaned the project. It solved the problem and project run successfully