# Unknown class PFQueryTableView in Interface Builder file Swift/Parse Error

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I understand the error(Unknown class PFQueryTableView in Interface Builder file), but just can't give it a class. I watched one of Vea Software's tutorial on PFQueryTableViewController, and didnt mention anything about this, it worked with him, but doesn't work now. I don't know exactly where this class should be, I tried adding it into my PFQueryTableViewController class and add PFQueryTableView next to it but i just get errors. Any idea on how to solve this?[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Looks like your VC class is PFQueryTableViewController.  You should paint a UITableViewController in IB, and set its custom class to PFQueryTableViewController.  There's no need to change its table view to a PFQueryTableView (as far as I know).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by paint a UITableViewController in IB? (I'm reasonably new to Swift)

Comment: In the storyboard, when you add a view controller (paint), the thing you should drag (from the lower-left object palette) is a UITableViewController.

Comment: Thats what i did during the tutorial. He mentioned nothing about setting the tableview, and I'm getting an error for not giving it a custom class?

Comment: Right, you shouldn't have to setup a class for a view.  Only for the viewController.

Comment: Thats just what I'm stuck, Xcode wants me to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCODE 7.1 Swift 2 Unknown class in Interface Builder file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033129/xcode-7-1-swift-2-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file)

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your problem? If not, you can try to set it as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33034445/3367915) which has solved my problem:
In storyboard below the Custom Class field the module is set to None. Change that to your app module or just remove and enter class again, it should set to default like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuVFL.png)