# iOS - get frame of UIView at runtime which was created with Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm working on my app which uses a graph to visualize some data. I'm using this nice Scrollable-GraphView for that: https://github.com/philackm/Scrollable-GraphView

Because this is only a class which inherits from UIScrollView, it's not possible to use it with Interface Builder (it also doesn't have the init(withCoder:) function implemented).

I now want to add a UIView with Interface Builder, which has all the necessary constraints to be sized properly at runtime. How can I "replace" that UIView with my GraphView at runtime?

This method is used for creating my graph at runtime:

```
private func createDarkGraph(frame: CGRect) -> ScrollableGraphView {
    let graphView = ScrollableGraphView(frame: frame)

    // ... some customization

    return graphView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In interface builder you can drag a UIScrollView and set up constraint like normal UIScrollView, and then set the class to `ScrollableGraphView`, select the correct module (import!!! See this link [XCODE 7.1 Swift 2 Unknown class in Interface Builder file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033129/xcode-7-1-swift-2-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file)). If you get the scrollView instance from interface builder (creating outlet .etc), it must be the instance of `ScrollableGraphView`. That should work just fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried that before, but when you use a custom view with interface builder you need to implement the *init(coder:)* initializer. But that isn't the case.

Comment: You get the error "Unknown class ScrollableGraphView in Interface Builder file swift" ?  You should  select the module below the `Class` field. See this link [XCODE 7.1 Swift 2 Unknown class in Interface Builder file] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033129/xcode-7-1-swift-2-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file) . After I set the module, it works. I will update my answer.

Comment: I'm doing it exactly as you're doing it. I have an IBOutlet connected to my ViewController which contains the ScrollableGraphView. But when I run my app I get the error `fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file ../MyApp/Libraries/ScrollableGraphView.swift, line 244`

Comment: And that's because `init(coder:)` only produces a fatal error. How did you do that? What module do I have to chose? I don't have one listed there..

Comment: It's working now! I just removed the `fatal error(...)` call in the `init(coder:)` and placed `super.init(coder: aDecoder)` there. Thank you!

Comment: My ScrollableGraphView.swift file, line 244 was jsut call super.int(code: aDecoder) : ` required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }`  . Maybe the version of our ScrollableGraphView.swift file are different.  Happy to solve the problem . @beeef