# Xcode: Different targets have different rootViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appdelegate

I've got an app that's functional (in the app store).  In the past, we only had one version of our app with one Target in Xcode.  Our development cycle is getting a little more complex, so we want to have two Xcode targets: production and development.  These two targets would have two different bundle identifiers so we can have the different versions running on the phone at the same time.  This is a similar strategy to this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/68613/create-paid-lite-version-iphone-app

I've basically followed the raywenderlich instructions to duplicate my target and set a preprocessor macro.  The only change so far is using a different icon.

The "Original" version of the app is the "production" version. The newly duplicated target is the "development" version.

I'm using a storyboard where the `LaunchViewController` is set as the `Is Initial View Controller` option.

In the AppDelegate, I have code that gets the root viewcontroller via `window?.visibleViewController` and sets some information on it:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    // ...
    guard let launchVC = window?.visibleViewController as? LaunchViewController else {
        NSLog("visibleViewController is nil or not LaunchViewController")
        return
    }
    NSLog("calling startUserManagerAndLogin  - launch")
    launchVC.startUserManagerAndLogin()
    // ...
    return true
}
```

In the original (production) version of the app, everything continues to work fine.  I see the following line in the console, and the app launches correctly:

```
... Visible View Controller: Optional(<MyApp.LaunchViewController: 0x7f84dea02a00>)
```

However in the development version of the app.   I'm seeing the `guard` case fail.  Here's what I see in the console:

```
... Visible View Controller: Optional(<UIViewController: 0x7fbd1e509570>)
... visibleViewController is nil or not LaunchViewController
```

The root view controller is different between the production and development targets.  I don't see how the root view controller can be different between two targets unless I explicitly set that (which I didn't).

I checked the project files and the "General -> Deployment Info" is the same between the two targets.  I also checked the storyboard, and there's nothing there that specifies different view controllers.

Any ideas what's going on or how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gah! FFS I figured it out.  Turns out there was another log line that I missed that said:

```
... Unknown class _TtC8MyApp20LaunchViewController in Interface Builder file.
```

I found this out because I tried instantiating my `LaunchViewController` by hand (from the storyboard) and got this error as well.  I figured out that the module was wrong.

I then found the SO question: [XCODE 7.1 Swift 2 Unknown class in Interface Builder file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033129/xcode-7-1-swift-2-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file) which helped me find that there were some old storyboard elements that didn't have `Inherit Module From Target` selected.  I toggled the checkbox to on, and now it's working.  Phew.

[image]