# Unknown class <myClass> in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

i get this error whenever i try to segue from one viewController to another. theres no code and ive been going through google pages and questions on here for hours and i cannot find a solution.

Comment: What happens if you do a full project search for your class name?

Comment: In interface builder, have you specified a view controller class? Alternately, try this--> http://stackoverflow.com/a/24924967/4475605

Comment: first comment: it shows me the class declaration. and shows up as the VC class and storyboard ID.
second comment: i tried that and it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You experience this problem because:

- You might have assigned a class to a View Controller in .storyboard file, which does not exist
- You might have assigned a class to a View Controller in .storyboard before you created it and thus it failed to automatically set an appropriate Module.
- You might have assigned class to a VC, which does not inherit from UIViewController.

Solution: Reassign VC class with help of the dropdown list OR manually chose "Current - Project Name" module from Module dropdown list. Make sure your custom class "extends" (inherits from) UIViewController.