# Cannot access storyboard in resource bundle file inside iOS static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, static

I am creating a static library in iOS. I am using a storyboard file in it. In order to do so I have created a resource bundle file named 'OfferWallResources.bundle' in which I have added my storyboard file named 'Offerwall.storyboard'. I am trying to access the storyboard inside the static library using the following code:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"OfferWallResources.bundle"];
    UIStoryboard *s=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Offerwall" bundle:bundle];
```

But my app is crashing with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard
>   named 'Offerwall' in bundle NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)'

I also tried to access the same storyboard file in the target project using the same code and it worked. But, I want to access it inside the library. I don't get where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not instantiating the bundle properly. Try with `[NSBundle bundleWithPath:]` or `[NSBundle bundleWithURL:]`.

Comment: I tried using [NSBundle bundleWithPath:]. Getting the following error now: Unknown class OfferwallViewController in Interface Builder file. This viewcontroller is present in my storyboard file and I am instantiating it in the library using the code: OfferwallViewController *o=[s instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OfferwallViewController"];

Comment: And in the storyboard you have a view controller with the class set to OfferWallViewController and the identifier to "OfferwallViewController"? Anyway, this is another problem, getting the storyboard file seems to be working.

Comment: How to deal with the second problem?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file

Comment: And btw, set the answer as correct if it fixed the problem :)