# Cannot instantiate viewcontroller present in the storyboard in resource bundle file inside iOS static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, static

I am creating a static library in iOS. I am using a storyboard file in it. In order to do so I have created a resource bundle file named `OfferWallResources.bundle` in which I have added my storyboard file named `Offerwall.storyboard`. I have a `UIViewController` with identifier `OfferWallViewController` in the storyboard: When I try to instantiate it inside the static library, I get the following error message:

Unknown class `OfferwallViewController` in Interface Builder file

The code for instantiating the `UIViewController` is as follows:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"OfferWallResources" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
    UIStoryboard *s=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Offerwall" bundle:bundle];
    OfferwallViewController *o=[s instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OfferwallViewController"];
```

I also made `OfferwallViewController` the initial `UIViewController` of the storyboard and tried using the following code:

```
OfferwallViewController *o=[s instantiateInitialViewController];
```

But, I am still facing the same issue when I am instantiating the `UIViewController` inside the static library.

I tried following the link: [Xcode 6 Strange Bug: Unknown class in Interface Builder file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file)
But nothing happens when I press Enter inside the Module option of the given viewcontroller.

I am still not getting where I am going wrong. I am using Xcode 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be detecting your static library as a Module.

A workaround can be to subclass OfferwallViewController in your current application and then use the subclass in storyboard.

PS: I guess static libraries are not meant to store resources like storyboards, xibs or images. You should use Xcode Frameworks.

Comment: Kataria: Thats why I am using a resource bundle file 'OfferWallResources.bundle' where I have placed the storyboard file and the OfferWallViewController class files.