# Unknown class ViewController(any) in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, xcode7, swift2

2016-05-11 16:21:42.262 tech[3889:176910] Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file.

2016-05-11 16:21:42.336 tech[3889:176910] Unknown class LoginViewController in Interface Builder file.

2016-05-11 16:21:42.372 tech[3889:176910] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key loginBtn.'
*** First throw call stack:

please help me, i know this question is already asked here([Xcode 6 Strange Bug: Unknown class in Interface Builder file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file)) but still i am not able to solve my problem, please help:(

Comment: unknown class is different problem...check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reasonthis-class-is-not-key-valu to get solution to your problem

Comment: can anyone one please explain this line "
 
Your view controller may have the wrong class in your xib.

I downloaded your project.

The error you are getting is

    'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x3927310> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key string.'

It is caused by the Second view controller in MainWindow.xib having a class of UIViewController instead of SecondView. Changing to the correct class resolves the problem. "

Comment: I am using xcode 7 and I think there is no file of name MainWindow.xib

Answer (score 0):

If you have deleted referencing outlet or action method of button from code the select that button from interface builder and open `connection inspecto`r and from referencing outlet or action close that connection.

[image]