# application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method getting called on app crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Please, someone, give me solution how to solve this problem?

I don't know why

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method is getting called on app crash (crash is created by myself to observe this problem, and I can fix this crash).
I tested it by showing `UILocalNotification` and `NSUserDefaults`.

The problem is actually observed on `iPhone 6 with iOS 9.3.2`,
But with `iPhone 5C with iOS 10.0.2` everything is OK (`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method is not getting called on app crash).

The project is written in `Objective C`.

To observe this problem there should be the real crash, not taking an app into `background/inactive` state and swiping it up by the user.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in that function then post a screenshot of the stacktrace of when this breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 2):

Add below line in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
```

Then, add below code in your appDelegate to get cause of exception:

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
  NSLog(@"Exception : %@", exception);
  NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
  // Internal error reporting
}
```

Comment: What would be the swift equivalent of this?

Comment: NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in                                                         }

Comment: Thanks, but what about the void uncaughtExceptionHandler portion?

Comment: @FeleciaGenet you can find similar for swift https://stackoverflow.com/a/55997459/3236890

Answer (score 0):

Click on Project target, Change Deployment Target to 9.3

Comment: Deployment target 9.3 still covers iOS 9.3.2. But why should I change it? Maybe there any other problem

Comment: Crash is created by myself to observe strange calling of `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Does `ExceptionBreakpoint` help here?