# Unknown class in Interface Builder file - Xcode 8 Swift 3

Tags: xcode, autolayout, swift3, interface-builder, xcode8

I ran into the following error

> Unknown class TutorialViewController.swift in Interface Builder file.

when renaming the default files `Main.storyboard` and `ViewController.swift` to my desired naming convention of `TutorialView.storyboard` and `TutorialViewController.swift` respectively.

I renamed the files by physically renaming the file names in Xcode and updating the class name of `TutorialViewController.swift`.

After renaming, I tried to fix the link from `TutorialView.storyboard` to `TutorialViewController.swift` by updating the storyboard's `Custom Class` to `TutorialViewController`, which is the correct way to complete the link. This in fact caused the above error.

*Disclaimer: I'm aware this is similar to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file) but I wanted to make this question and answer my solution, as that post does not have an accepted answer. I'm hoping I can save someone all the time it took me to figure this out.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What ended up solving my problem was creating a new project and seeing how the original `Main.storyboard` references its .swift file in the XML, which looks like this

```
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="Sandbox" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

where the important aspect is `customClass="ViewController"`

By taking this, and editing my project's `TutorialView.storyboard` by hand and adding in `customClass="TutorialViewController` I resolved the error.

Answer (score 11):

Check if the `Inherit from Target` is selected in the interface builder to your custom view. That actually did the trick for me.

If your view happens to be within a `.bundle` file that gets copied to a different target, then you'll need to explicitly set the module target.

If you have multiple targets, then check if the custom class is selected for all the targets or at least the one which you are running.

Answer (score 4):

You could also try selecting the CustomClass -- Class again to your class name and hit return. It would help update the class name associated with the viewController.

Comment: Yea, this will work to "refresh" the reference but if the reference was incorrect in the first place, it'll have no affect. Thanks for the answer!