# Xcode 8 error: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key enemyTitleLabel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I get the following error message when a user presses a button that uses a "Show" command to present `SixthViewController`:

> 2017-08-03 15:19:12.180963-0400 App[5298:1956556] Unknown class
>   SixthViewController in Interface Builder file. 2017-08-03
>   15:19:12.187793-0400 App[5298:1956556] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key enemyTitleLabel.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x18a4defe0 0x188f40538 0x18a4deca8 0x18aef468c 0x190974e94 0x190b18c70 0x18a3fffac 0x190b17664
>   0x190977e6c 0x1907420b0 0x1906107ac 0x1906106e0 0x190fe25b8
>   0x19095d5ec 0x1909819b8 0x1909847e4 0x190701794 0x190987f30
>   0x190cc86fc 0x190dd9600 0x190dd9408 0x190978a14 0x10002f10c
>   0x10002f184 0x190645c54 0x190645bd4 0x190630148 0x1906454b8
>   0x190644fd4 0x19064036c 0x190610f80 0x190e0aa20 0x190e0517c
>   0x190e055a8 0x18a48d42c 0x18a48cd9c 0x18a48a9a8 0x18a3bada4
>   0x18be25074 0x190675c9c 0x10003f708 0x1893c959c) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I'm able to load `SixthViewController` as long as none of the `UIButton` or `UILabels` are linked to anything; but as soon as I link any of them (not just `enemyTextLabel`), I get the same error (obviously the key changes depending on which element I linked).

I've already tried unlinking/relinking everything, and making sure that there are no typos in the code, and no matter what, the error persists when the items are relinking.

I've looked at questions reporting the same error and the solution seems to be to double-check for accidental links/typos/mistakes in the code. I've checked over my project multiple times and can't find any of these.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: You still have a outlet in your StoryBoard which should be connected to your code, but the outlet in your code is not there. It is searching for it, but can not find it in your code. At least, I think that is the problem.

Comment: I suspected that, but the "enemyTitleLabel" outlet is in fact linked to my code with "@IBOutlet weak var enemyTitleLabel: UILabel!"

Comment: Is your `SixthViewController` included in your app target?  The interface builder can't find it so it's just creating a plain `UIViewController` and trying to hook your outlets up to it.

Comment: How can I check if it is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 6 Strange Bug: Unknown class in Interface Builder file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably because as a Swift subclass, your view controller is probably actually getting a namespaced Objective-C name, i.e. SomeProject.SixthViewController, whereas the nib loading mechanism is just looking for SixthViewController. This usually happens if the Module field is blank in Interface Builder. You should check your xib/storyboard where the view controller is referenced, and in the Identity inspector, make sure the Module field is set to your project's module. If you do this, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Open Xcode Select target that you run Code Open build Phase --> Compile Sources.

Add the class (viewController.m) in which "enemyTitleLabel" label is there.

[image].

Answer (score 0):

Right click on each item in the controller (or cell) that contains the enemyTitleLabel label.  Scroll through the popup menu until you reach the referencing outlet section, and check that each referencing outlet in the referencing outlet is in the class of this controller (or a tableview cell).

This is a common problem I face when developing especially when using tableview cells.