# App won't load upon launch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This is the module text:

```
    2017-09-17 01:39:10.218262-0500 Metropolitan League 1.5.2[2274:615110] Unknown class _TtC25Metropolitan_League_1_5_111OpenMapView in Interface Builder file.
2017-09-17 01:39:10.256692-0500 Metropolitan League 1.5.2[2274:615110] Unknown class _TtC25Metropolitan_League_1_5_27mapView in Interface Builder file.
2017-09-17 01:39:10.290714-0500 Metropolitan League 1.5.2[2274:615110] libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 2274 (Metropolitan League 1.5.2) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled
2017-09-17 01:39:10.290764-0500 Metropolitan League 1.5.2[2274:615110] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see <rdar://problem/11744455>)
2017-09-17 01:39:10.337915-0500 Metropolitan League 1.5.2[2274:615110] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x12bd12660> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mapView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x188026fe0 0x186a88538 0x188026ca8 0x188a3b64c 0x18e4bc2fc 0x18e6600d8 0x187f47fac 0x18e65eacc 0x18e4bf2d4 0x18e28946c 0x18e157b68 0x18e20fff0 0x18e20fec8 0x18e20f1f8 0x18e20ec2c 0x18e20e7e0 0x18e20e744 0x18e15507c 0x18b345274 0x18b339de8 0x18b339ca8 0x18b2b534c 0x18b2dc3ac 0x18b2dce78 0x187fd49a8 0x187fd2630 0x187f02dc4 0x18e1c2384 0x18e1bd058 0x1000f27a8 0x186f1159c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

What all do I need to look for in the storyboard and swift files to fit this issue?

The class is correctly named and connected.

Comment: You probably have a dead `IBOutlet` in your interface builder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v)

Comment: The mapView has no dead outlets and I deleted the extra outlets I have on the storyboard with no luck.

Comment: Version 8.3.3  .

Comment: When I get an error like that I control-click on the storyboard and choose "Open As" » "Source Code" and then search for the `mapView`. If worst comes to worst, delete "Derived Data" folder and restart Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `IBOutlet of mapView` is connected properly from your viewcontroller in storyboard. This might be the root cause of your crash.

Try reconnecting the mapView from storyboard to your ViewController class. It will solve your issue

Comment: @Alexander Please elaborate in detail as the error shown by your relates to IBOutlet . So please elaborate a bit

Answer (score 1):

You have an `IBOutlet` that is invalid. Do the following to fix it:

1. Go to your Storyboard
2. Click on the view controller that has the `MapView`
3. Click on Connections inspector button on the right meny (the one with the right arrow) / or right click on the MapView
4. Remove all the outlets
5. Go to your code and remove the outlet for the MapView
6. Re-create the outlet
7. Run your project

Comment: Now my app is launching but freezing when I try to switch to a tableview. It says "Unknown class parksTable in Interface Builder file." but I've deleted the connection and re-created it and it still doesn't work. Inheriting from Target doesn't change anything either.

Comment: @Alexander, checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file) to solve that issue.

Comment: Like I said, that doesn't change anything either. My issue is now with loading data from a database to a table view because the VC containing the tableview freezes the app

Comment: Okey, maybe you should ask another question for that issue since the first one is solved or update your current question with relevant code.

Comment: The current issue isn't solved. It still appears in the console. It just doesn't freeze where it did previously.

Comment: @Alexander, do you have the possibility to upload your code to Dropbox/Google drive so that I can download it and take a look for you?

Answer (score 1):

This is because, you might have created an Outlet with name: 'mapView' and later changed it's name to something else in your source. Please verify that the outlet name you connected in the UI and the name you are referring in source code is same. If this doesn't fix the issue please provide more details. Hope this helps!

Comment: That is not the case. Xcode is uncooperative in that it'll load the mapView while saying it is an unknown class. I fixed the issue of the app not launching fully but now I have a different problem where my table data won't load and freezes when I try to open the table view

Comment: @Alexander, please let us know how did you fix that issue. And please elaborate on the table load issue may be in another question.