# Xcode project throws NSUnknownKeyException after starting project on Version 10.1

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10, xcode9.4

I have an Xcode project on my older Mac that I finished building (Xcode version 9.4.1). There it workes fine and it is ready for the upload in the AppStore. Because My Mac can't run macOS mojave I borrowed another Mac with the latest Xcode Version (10.1) when I run the project there I get the following exception:

```
2019-03-03 11:21:20.941643+0100 Schoolcheck_Schüler[6018:110054] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.

2019-03-03 11:21:21.052628+0100 Schoolcheck_Schüler[6018:110054] Unknown class _TtC20Schoolcheck_Schüler12ChooseSchool in Interface Builder file.

2019-03-03 11:21:21.086624+0100 Schoolcheck_Schüler[6018:110054] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fbab841cf20> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key LabelSchoolName.'

*** First throw call stack:

(

0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110e761bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110414735 objc_exception_throw + 48

2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110e75d29 -[NSException raise] + 9

3   Foundation                          0x000000010fe3fde4 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292

4   UIKitCore                           0x0000000116708292 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87

5   UIKitCore                           0x000000011699f573 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109

6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110e61cfd -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 317

7   UIKitCore                           0x000000011699c2b9 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1814

8   UIKitCore                           0x000000011670f452 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 383

9   UIKitCore                           0x000000011670fddc -[UIViewController loadView] + 177

10  UIKitCore                           0x00000001167100ee -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 175

11  UIKitCore                           0x0000000116710940 -[UIViewController view] + 27

12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000116d67c53 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 122

13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000116d6836e -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 294

14  UIKitCore                           0x0000000116d7b5c0 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42

15  UIKitCore                           0x0000000116d28833 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4595

16  UIKitCore                           0x0000000116d2dc2f -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1623

17  UIKitCore                           0x000000011654c4e9 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 866

18  UIKitCore                           0x000000011655529c +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153

19  UIKitCore                           0x000000011654c126 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 233

20  UIKitCore                           0x000000011654cae0 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1085

21  UIKitCore                           0x000000011654acb5 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 795

22  UIKitCore                           0x000000011654a95f -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 435

23  UIKitCore                           0x000000011654fa90 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 584

24  UIKitCore                           0x000000011655080e _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100

25  UIKitCore                           0x000000011654f7ef -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 221

26  UIKitCore                           0x000000011655493a -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392

27  UIKitCore                           0x0000000116d2c44e -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 515

28  UIKitCore                           0x00000001168d0d09 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 357

29  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011d8dd2da -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448

30  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011d8e8443 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 271

31  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011d8e7b3a __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 53

32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001143e3602 _dispatch_client_callout + 8

33  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001143e6b78 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 301

34  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011d91cba8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30

35  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011d91c860 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 457

36  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011d91ce40 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45

37  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ddb721 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17

38  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110ddaf93 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243

39  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110dd563f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263

40  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110dd4e11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625

41  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011a9361dd GSEventRunModal + 62

42  UIKitCore                           0x0000000116d2f81d UIApplicationMain + 140

43  Schoolcheck_SchuÃàler               0x000000010f95f494 main + 68

44  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000114459575 start + 1

)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

(lldb)
```

I ran the project on my old mac on my external harddrive and it worked fine. After that I tried running the project on the newer mac on the external harddrive but it did't work.

I checked all classes and every class is connected right.

I also deleted the connection of the outlets and reconnected them. It chanched nothing.

Thank you in advance,

Manuel

Answer (score 0):

Based on your crash log. There's a good chance that the IBOutLet named `LabelSchoolName` been removed from your code. You could look at the UIViewController refer to it and re-add.

Comment: I noted there two issue here. About failed to build with `Unknown class in interface builder file`. This may help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file

Comment: The problem was that I had a German Umlaut (ü) in the name, once I changed it to ue it worked fine.