# Custom UIView not loading XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib

I am trying to add customized UIView XIB, but its crashing when fetching NIB.

UIView class .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface DatesView : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fromDateLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fromMonthYearLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fromDayLabel;



@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *toDateLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *toonthYearLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *toDayLabel;

@end
```

UIView class .m

```
#import "DatesView.h"

@implementation DatesView

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initializeSubviews];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initializeSubviews];

    }
    return self;
}
-(void)initializeSubviews {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSBundle *bundle = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"DatesView" owner:self options:nil]firstObject];
    [self addSubview:self.contentView];

    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;

}



@end
```

Xib

[image]

A crash report in console

```
Unknown class _TtC3EVA9DatesView in Interface Builder file.
```

This is where it's stopping the execution

[image]

Comment: show the crash report

Comment: Why **Module** is `none` ?? Select on option **Inherit Module From Target**. Clean and run your project.

Comment: check the edit @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Thanks @dahiya_boy, your suggestion is helpful, now its leading crash at another line, saying " Unknown class _TtC3EVA9DatesView in Interface Builder file."

Comment: @Codecracker Make sure `File's Owner` is assigned. And edit your question with current status. Might be this helpful -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to instantiating views from xib files. One common issue is assigning the Class to the wrong thing.

Using your code, make sure you have assigned the class to **File's Owner**:

[image]

Here's a simplified example from your image / code:

---

**DatesView.xib source**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="15505" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="15510"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="DatesView">
            <connections>
                <outlet property="contentView" destination="iN0-l3-epB" id="Yhm-Z4-6Rd"/>
                <outlet property="fromDateLabel" destination="cfP-lM-bLV" id="QeZ-ly-bag"/>
                <outlet property="toDateLabel" destination="WGv-5C-gVM" id="Wl6-DR-OuA"/>
            </connections>
        </placeholder>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="76"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" text="From Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="cfP-lM-bLV">
                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="134" height="33.5"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="28"/>
                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="To Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="WGv-5C-gVM">
                    <rect key="frame" x="266.5" y="8" width="100.5" height="33.5"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.97305089235305786" green="0.92194973774024858" blue="0.86304229628289908" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="28"/>
                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.78049301826098361" green="0.95023679298999175" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="vUN-kp-3ea" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="cfP-lM-bLV" secondAttribute="bottom" priority="999" constant="8" id="8mH-tY-Xpd"/>
                <constraint firstItem="WGv-5C-gVM" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="vUN-kp-3ea" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="BMT-uj-nrj"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="WGv-5C-gVM" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="Dyv-OC-Mej"/>
                <constraint firstItem="cfP-lM-bLV" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="vUN-kp-3ea" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="Yoh-Mn-Epa"/>
                <constraint firstItem="cfP-lM-bLV" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="vUN-kp-3ea" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="oTg-QC-oRP"/>
            </constraints>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="vUN-kp-3ea"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="138.40000000000001" y="330.13493253373315"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

---

**DatesView.h**

```
//  DatesView.h
//  Created by Don Mag on 1/30/20.

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface DatesView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fromDateLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *toDateLabel;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

---

**DatesView.m**

```
//  DatesView.m
//  Created by Don Mag on 1/30/20.

#import "DatesView.h"

@implementation DatesView

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initializeSubviews];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initializeSubviews];

    }
    return self;
}
-(void)initializeSubviews {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSBundle *bundle = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"DatesView" owner:self options:nil]firstObject];
    [self addSubview:self.contentView];

    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;

}

@end
```

---

**TestXIBViewController.h**

```
//  TestXIBViewController.h
//  Created by Don Mag on 1/30/20.

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface TestXIBViewController : UIViewController

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

---

**TestXIBViewController.m**

```
//  TestXIBViewController.m
//  Created by Don Mag on 1/30/20.

#import "TestXIBViewController.h"
#import "DatesView.h"

@interface TestXIBViewController ()

@end

@implementation TestXIBViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    DatesView *dv = [DatesView new];
    dv.fromDateLabel.text = @"12";
    dv.toDateLabel.text = @"19";

    [self.view addSubview:dv];

    dv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    UILayoutGuide *g = [self.view safeAreaLayoutGuide];

    // constrain Top, Leading, Trailing at 40-pts
    // NO Bottom or Height constraint
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [dv.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant: 40.0],
        [dv.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant: 40.0],
        [dv.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant: -40.0],
    ]];

}

@end
```

---

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

R-click on the xib "file's Owner" and see if there are any orange warning triangles. delete the references if there are. if you had something referencing an object on the XIB and then delete the object, it will crash until you delete the reference as well.